# Textbook with a comparative approach to discrete and continuous topology and their ramifications in analysis

Tags: general-topology, analysis, discrete-mathematics, differential-geometry, reference-request

Topology is often described as the way to define the continuity of maps. But one can also define topologies over finite/discrete/countable spaces.

Additionally, one can often draw analogies between "discrete" analysis (sequences, series, the derivative as $u_{n+1} - u_n$, recurrence equations) and "continuous" analysis (functions, integrals, derivatives as $\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{h}$, differential equations).

Finally, considering something like $\mathbb{Z}[i]$, the Gaussian integers, there's definitely some graph theoretic concepts that could be of use to help define the notion of a "discrete neighborhood".

So my questions are:

1. does there exist a textbook which gives a thorough treatment of both "discrete analysis" and "continuous analysis" side-by-side, with examples; with topological grounding, preferably up to differential geometry ? Is there any textbook that's anywhere remotely in that vein ?
2. Alternatively, is there a textbook that presents topology as a "continuous graph theory", where "normal" graph theory is understood to also include graphs with an infinite (countable) number of vertices, as well as graphs with $n$-ary edges (hypergraphs) ?
3. Is there a textbook that presents what "continuity of a map" would mean over discrete topological spaces, in depth, and its distinction (and relations) with "normal" topology ?